# Is it possible to control which Google Maps scripts get fetched (JavaScript API)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

So I am using Google Maps for an autocomplete text input for cities. The script I'm calling has an src like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&types=(cities)
```

I see in the network tab that this actually downloads quite a few external google scripts:

```
common.js
util.js
controls.js
places_impl.js
stats.js
```

Collectively, these scripts are over 100kb... That's equal to the size of my *entire* application (gzipped). Is this really necessary just for a places autocomplete? Is there any way to pass params into the request url that control what is downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all scripts which Google Maps JS API need to function properly, to display Map, etc. But if you want ONLY Places Autocomplete, and you don't even want to display the map, then there is a way for you to not download ANY libraries.

Just make a request to [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests), something like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=TEXT&types=(cities)&language=en&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

for autocomplete results every time user inputs something into you search input box (or preferably with some throttling). `Google Places API` is not part of `Google Maps JS API` you are using in your project, it's a separate API only for Places.

Comment: Do you have examples of this? I was looking for npm packages (preferably React-based), and haven't found anything useful that isn't horribly bloated.